# Window function inside aggregate function error

Tags: function, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate, window-functions

I get the following error message:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use a window function inside an aggregate function. Please use the inner window function in a sub-query.

How can I "transform" the below code to have it work?

```py
Master_Table_All_2 = Master_Table_All.withColumn("cumulative_paid_in_target_currency_period", F.sum(Master_Table_All.damage_amount_target_currency_in_period.over(Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("date_end").rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
Master_Table_All_2 = Master_Table_All.withColumn(
    "cumulative_paid_in_target_currency_period",
    F.sum("damage_amount_target_currency_in_period").over(Window
        .partitionBy("key")
        .orderBy("date_end")
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    )
)
```